# Running RMarkdown from PHP

Tags: php, command-line, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to run RMarkdown from PHP using the **exec()** command. When trying to knit my .Rmd file, I receive the following error:

```
Execution haltedArray ( 
[0] => Error in with_pandoc_safe_environment(system(paste(shQuote(path), "--version"), : 
[1] => The 'HOME' environment variable must be set before running Pandoc. 
[2] => Calls: <Anonymous> ... FUN -> get_pandoc_version -> with_pandoc_safe_environment 
[3] => Execution halted )
```

The command `Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('path/to/file.Rmd')"` works fine on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

It says right there what is wrong: it needs a `HOME` env var to be set. Not sure what's your environment, but you can find out it's value in the shell where the command is working as intended:

`echo $HOME`

Then prepend that value to your `exec()` call:

`exec("HOME=/the/path/you/got/before $theRMarkdownCommandYouNeed")`

Or you may need another path, specific to the user you PHP is running under.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to set `HOME` in `/etc/R/Renviron`.

Answer (score 0):

In R you can check environment with `Sys.getenv()` function and set a value with `Sys.setenv(HOME="/home/YOURHOME/"`. After you set it correctly (like your `echo $HOME` in default shell), than pandoc will not complain during `rmarkdown::render`.